# vite-plugin-pwa Could not load /home/ezekiel/Downloads/project-v

Tags: node.js, npm, vuejs3, vite, netlify

I'm trying to build both on netlify and on my project on my computer using npm run build, But i keep getting error.
I'm tired of it already.

[vite-plugin-pwa] Could not load /home/ezekiel/Downloads/project-v1/src/assets/illustrations/landing/app-1.png?width=740&height=490&format=webp (imported by src/pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang.ts): Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'width' in undefined
error during build:
TypeError: Could not load /home/ezekiel/Downloads/project-v1/src/assets/illustrations/landing/app-1.png?width=740&height=490&format=webp (imported by src/pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang.ts): Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'width' in undefined
at /home/ezekiel/Downloads/project-v1/node_modules/imagetools-core/dist/index.cjs:391:30
at Array.filter ()
at Object.resolveConfigs (/home/ezekiel/Downloads/project-v1/node_modules/imagetools-core/dist/index.cjs:391:10)
at Object.load (/home/ezekiel/Downloads/project-v1/node_modules/vite-imagetools/dist/index.cjs:43:49)
at /home/ezekiel/Downloads/project-v1/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:19990:25
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

It looks like its a vite error that keeps complaining about my static file setup

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.